# Reflection: Get values from Scanned Class with Annotation

Tags: java, reflection, reflections

So Im trying to get the file with the searched annotation, like this:

```
package com.nikita.Nikitos;

import java.util.Set;

import org.reflections.Reflections;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.nikita.Nikitos");
        Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(lombok.Getter.class);
        System.out.println(annotated);

}
}
```

Im sure that my codes finds the file in which the annotation is located. Because I get following output in my console:

> Reflections took 138 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 1 keys and 1 values

So there has to be a value. But my List that Im trying to print out is empty. So how do I get these values?

The file that contains the annotation looks like this:

```
package com.nikita.Nikitos;

import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
public class App
{
    int zahl;
    public App (int zahl) {
        zahl = this.zahl;
    }


}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is because `@Getter` is not using `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html). `Getter` is itself annotated with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)`. As a result, your `App` class file does not retain that it's annotated by `Getter` and Reflections can't find it.

Comment: Is there any work around for that?

Comment: I do not think so. I don't believe lombok annotations are meant to be scanned for during runtime (and are probably removed during the annotation processing step).  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to disable all Lombok.experimental.* features. When you want you can paste your comment as an answer. I’ll accept it

Comment: Do you understand the Lombok is modifying the code *at compile time*? So whatever you do *at runtime* can’t have effects like “disable all Lombok.experimental.* features”. There’s, by the way, a much simpler approach. Just don’t use Lombok in the first place. Just write down the three lines of actual code for the getter method and remove the `import` and the `@Getter` annotation. When you are using an up-to-date Java versio, you can simply declare `public record App(int zahl) {}` to get an immutable type with an accessor method without the need for external tools.

Comment: I solved it with SonarQube rules. & I know that you can declare that yourself. I just wanted to discourage the use of lombok.experimental annotation in my Project. The getter was just an example for me, so I could test on lombok annotations